# Enabling dir listing for Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8

Is this correct method to enable shared dir listings on Tomcat :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>MyProject</display-name>

      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>debug</param-name>
            <param-value>0</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>listings</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Project name where web.xml is contained is MyProject. I have other projects running on Tomcat where dir listing is turned off. This works but I'm not sure it's correct to overrride `org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet` in this way ?

Comment: You have done in right way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat document mentions this [here](http://www.ino.tifr.res.in:8080/docs/default-servlet.html#what) regarding overriding `DefaultServlet` -

> You can override DefaultServlet with you own implementation and use
>   that in your web.xml declaration

So clearly it is meant to be overridden whenever it suits your use case and for directory listing it seems absolutely fine to override.